# How to solve Google Cloud Storage Upload Error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting a pretty stupid error right now. I've upload dozens of video files to my Google Cloud Storage, but, out of nowhere, it stopped to work and is only saying "error". Nothing more.
I dunno how to start to debug it...
[image]

Comment: Do you have more detail on the error? Did you go to Cloud Logging to understand what happened?

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for your answer. I entered on it and there's nothing there, neither in my notifications.

Comment: Can you try with gsutil? You should have more details on the error

Comment: This seems an issolate issue, its better to ask for support in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so they can help you understand what is happening